# Remove rows from data.table where all columns with names including "question" are NA

Tags: r, data.table

I have data from a survey for which any response to a question is considered valid, whether the questions before or after were answered.

All data for responses is in a data.table, in columns with names that start with "question"

```
> dt.x <- data.table(
    row = 1:5,
    question_a = c(NA,NA,"A","B","C"),
    question_b = c(NA,"A","B","C","D")
)

> dt.x
   row question_a question_b
1:   1       <NA>       <NA>
2:   2       <NA>          A
3:   3          A          B
4:   4          B          C
5:   5          C          D
```

My goal is to remove rows which have no data in any columns starting with "question", but there may be data in other columns, eg the row column in the example.

```
   row question_a question_b
1:   2       <NA>          A
2:   3          A          B
3:   4          B          C
4:   5          C          D
```

How can I do this while grepping column names? I'm trying something like

```
> dt.x[!all(is.na(get(grep("question", names(dt.x), value = T))))]
   row question_a question_b
1:   1       <NA>       <NA>
2:   2       <NA>          A
3:   3          A          B
4:   4          B          C
5:   5          C          D
```

but not getting the results I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `rowSums` and count the `NA` values per row and select rows which do not have all `NA`

```
question_cols <- sum(grepl("^question", names(dt.x)))
dt.x[rowSums(is.na(dt.x[, -1])) != question_cols, ]

#   row question_a question_b
#1:   2       <NA>          A
#2:   3          A          B
#3:   4          B          C
#4:   5          C          D
```

Or using `dplyr`, `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
dt.x %>%
   filter_at(vars(starts_with("question")), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Comment: This is the easiest for me to understand. A slight improvement would be swapping `dt.x[, -1]` for `dt.x[, -(grep("^question", names(dt.x), invert = T)), with = F]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your case you could simply do:

```
dt.x[, .SD[!all(is.na(.SD))], by = row]
```

If there are more columns present:

```
dt.x[dt.x[, !all(is.na(.SD)), by = row, .SDcols = patterns("^question")]$V1]
```